# How to know the DataSpace from a group of tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

How can I query the Data Space of a group of tables in a Database?

for example:

Suppose that a SQL Server database has this tables: `Productsl, PRMDiscounts, PRMCities`

I want to know the sum of the Data Spaces for PRMDiscounts and PRMCities

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no thing as data space in sql servers, this will give you the space that the table is using including free space and index space

```
EXEC sp_spaceused 'PRMDiscounts'
EXEC sp_spaceused 'PRMCities'
```

example

```
EXEC sp_spaceused 'master..spt_values'



name        rows        reserved    data    index_size  unused
spt_values  2346        336 KB      128 KB  144 KB      64 KB
```

Comment: With Data Space I was referring to the field seen when doing right-click on a table -> Properties -> Storage in SqlServer Management Studio

Comment: [There is such a thing as data space in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190289.aspx). No idea if that terminology is new or not though.